# Solution of my Mozilla browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It works in chrome.But when i use with Mozilla Firefox then it shows this
" A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://localhost/tsdev_v2/resources/js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.js:6841"
 My code is...

```
<script>
/*$("table").stickyTableHeaders();*/
/*  $(function(){
    $("table").stickyTableHeaders();
});*/
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("table").stickyTableHeaders({fixedOffset:40}); 
});
</script>

<script>

;(function ($, window, undefined) {
'use strict';

var name = 'stickyTableHeaders',
    id = 0,
    defaults = {
        fixedOffset: 0,
        leftOffset: 0,
        marginTop: 0,
        objDocument: document,
        objHead: 'head',
        objWindow: window,
        scrollableArea: window
    };

function Plugin (el, options) {
    // To avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
    // to reference this class from internal events and functions.
    var base = this;

    // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
    base.$el = $(el);
    base.el = el;
    base.id = id++;

    // Listen for destroyed, call teardown
    base.$el.bind('destroyed',
        $.proxy(base.teardown, base));

    // Cache DOM refs for performance reasons
    base.$clonedHeader = null;
    base.$originalHeader = null;

    // Keep track of state
    base.isSticky = false;
    base.hasBeenSticky = false;
    base.leftOffset = null;
    base.topOffset = null;

    base.init = function () {
        base.setOptions(options);

        base.$el.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            // remove padding on <table> to fix issue #7
            $this.css('padding', 0);

            base.$originalHeader = $('thead:first', this);
            base.$clonedHeader = base.$originalHeader.clone();
            $this.trigger('clonedHeader.' + name, [base.$clonedHeader]);

            base.$clonedHeader.addClass('tableFloatingHeader');
            base.$clonedHeader.css('display', 'none');

            base.$originalHeader.addClass('tableFloatingHeaderOriginal');

            base.$originalHeader.after(base.$clonedHeader);

            base.$printStyle = $('<style type="text/css" media="print">' +
                '.tableFloatingHeader{display:none !important;}' +
                '.tableFloatingHeaderOriginal{position:static !important;}' +
                '</style>');
            base.$head.append(base.$printStyle);
        });

        base.updateWidth();
        base.toggleHeaders();
        base.bind();
    };

    base.destroy = function (){
        base.$el.unbind('destroyed', base.teardown);
        base.teardown();
    };

    base.teardown = function(){   
        if (base.isSticky) {
            base.$originalHeader.css('position', 'static');
        }
        $.removeData(base.el, 'plugin_' + name);
        base.unbind();

        base.$clonedHeader.remove();
        base.$originalHeader.removeClass('tableFloatingHeaderOriginal');
        base.$originalHeader.css('visibility', 'visible');
        base.$printStyle.remove();

        base.el = null;
        base.$el = null;
    };

    base.bind = function(){
        base.$scrollableArea.on('scroll.' + name, base.toggleHeaders);
        if (!base.isWindowScrolling) {
            base.$window.on('scroll.' + name + base.id, base.setPositionValues);
            base.$window.on('resize.' + name + base.id, base.toggleHeaders);
        }
        base.$scrollableArea.on('resize.' + name, base.toggleHeaders);
        base.$scrollableArea.on('resize.' + name, base.updateWidth);
    };

    base.unbind = function(){
        // unbind window events by specifying handle so we don't remove too much
        base.$scrollableArea.off('.' + name, base.toggleHeaders);
        if (!base.isWindowScrolling) {
            base.$window.off('.' + name + base.id, base.setPositionValues);
            base.$window.off('.' + name + base.id, base.toggleHeaders);
        }
        base.$scrollableArea.off('.' + name, base.updateWidth);
    };

    base.toggleHeaders = function () {
        if (base.$el) {
            base.$el.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    newLeft,
                    newTopOffset = base.isWindowScrolling ? (
                                isNaN(base.options.fixedOffset) ?
                                base.options.fixedOffset.outerHeight() :
                                base.options.fixedOffset
                            ) :
                            base.$scrollableArea.offset().top + (!isNaN(base.options.fixedOffset) ? base.options.fixedOffset : 0),
                    offset = $this.offset(),

                    scrollTop = base.$scrollableArea.scrollTop() + newTopOffset,
                    scrollLeft = base.$scrollableArea.scrollLeft(),

                    scrolledPastTop = base.isWindowScrolling ?
                            scrollTop > offset.top :
                            newTopOffset > offset.top,
                    notScrolledPastBottom = (base.isWindowScrolling ? scrollTop : 0) <
                            (offset.top + $this.height() - base.$clonedHeader.height() - (base.isWindowScrolling ? 0 : newTopOffset));

                if (scrolledPastTop && notScrolledPastBottom) {
                    newLeft = offset.left - scrollLeft + base.options.leftOffset;
                    base.$originalHeader.css({
                        'position': 'fixed',
                        'margin-top': base.options.marginTop,
                        'left': newLeft,
                        'z-index': 3 // #18: opacity bug
                    });
                    base.leftOffset = newLeft;
                    base.topOffset = newTopOffset;
                    base.$clonedHeader.css('display', '');
                    if (!base.isSticky) {
                        base.isSticky = true;
                        // make sure the width is correct: the user might have resized the browser while in static mode
                        base.updateWidth();
                        $this.trigger('enabledStickiness.' + name);
                    }
                    base.setPositionValues();
                } else if (base.isSticky) {
                    base.$originalHeader.css('position', 'static');
                    base.$clonedHeader.css('display', 'none');
                    base.isSticky = false;
                    base.resetWidth($('td,th', base.$clonedHeader), $('td,th', base.$originalHeader));
                    $this.trigger('disabledStickiness.' + name);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    base.setPositionValues = function () {
        var winScrollTop = base.$window.scrollTop(),
            winScrollLeft = base.$window.scrollLeft();
        if (!base.isSticky ||
                winScrollTop < 0 || winScrollTop + base.$window.height() > base.$document.height() ||
                winScrollLeft < 0 || winScrollLeft + base.$window.width() > base.$document.width()) {
            return;
        }
        base.$originalHeader.css({
            'top': base.topOffset - (base.isWindowScrolling ? 0 : winScrollTop),
            'left': base.leftOffset - (base.isWindowScrolling ? 0 : winScrollLeft)
        });
    };

    base.updateWidth = function () {
        if (!base.isSticky) {
            return;
        }
        // Copy cell widths from clone
        if (!base.$originalHeaderCells) {
            base.$originalHeaderCells = $('th,td', base.$originalHeader);
        }
        if (!base.$clonedHeaderCells) {
            base.$clonedHeaderCells = $('th,td', base.$clonedHeader);
        }
        var cellWidths = base.getWidth(base.$clonedHeaderCells);
        base.setWidth(cellWidths, base.$clonedHeaderCells, base.$originalHeaderCells);

        // Copy row width from whole table
        base.$originalHeader.css('width', base.$clonedHeader.width());
    };

    base.getWidth = function ($clonedHeaders) {
        var widths = [];
        $clonedHeaders.each(function (index) {
            var width, $this = $(this);

            if ($this.css('box-sizing') === 'border-box') {
                var boundingClientRect = $this[0].getBoundingClientRect();
                if(boundingClientRect.width) {
                    width = boundingClientRect.width; // #39: border-box bug
                } else {
                    width = boundingClientRect.right - boundingClientRect.left; // ie8 bug: getBoundingClientRect() does not have a width property
                }
            } else {
                var $origTh = $('th', base.$originalHeader);
                if ($origTh.css('border-collapse') === 'collapse') {
                    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
                        width = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this, null).width);
                    } else {
                        // ie8 only
                        var leftPadding = parseFloat($this.css('padding-left'));
                        var rightPadding = parseFloat($this.css('padding-right'));
                        // Needs more investigation - this is assuming constant border around this cell and it's neighbours.
                        var border = parseFloat($this.css('border-width'));
                        width = $this.outerWidth() - leftPadding - rightPadding - border;
                    }
                } else {
                    width = $this.width();
                }
            }

            widths[index] = width;
        });
        return widths;
    };

    base.setWidth = function (widths, $clonedHeaders, $origHeaders) {
        $clonedHeaders.each(function (index) {
            var width = widths[index];
            $origHeaders.eq(index).css({
                'min-width': width,
                'max-width': width
            });
        });
    };

    base.resetWidth = function ($clonedHeaders, $origHeaders) {
        $clonedHeaders.each(function (index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $origHeaders.eq(index).css({
                'min-width': $this.css('min-width'),
                'max-width': $this.css('max-width')
            });
        });
    };

    base.setOptions = function (options) {
        base.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        base.$window = $(base.options.objWindow);
        base.$head = $(base.options.objHead);
        base.$document = $(base.options.objDocument);
        base.$scrollableArea = $(base.options.scrollableArea);
        base.isWindowScrolling = base.$scrollableArea[0] === base.$window[0];
    };

    base.updateOptions = function (options) {
        base.setOptions(options);
        // scrollableArea might have changed
        base.unbind();
        base.bind();
        base.updateWidth();
        base.toggleHeaders();
    };

    // Run initializer
    base.init();
}

// A plugin wrapper around the constructor,
// preventing against multiple instantiations
$.fn[name] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var instance = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + name);
        if (instance) {
            if (typeof options === 'string') {
                instance[options].apply(instance);
            } else {
                instance.updateOptions(options);
            }
        } else if(options !== 'destroy') {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + name, new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
    });
};

})(jQuery, window);
</script>
```

In my jquery-1.8.3.js:6841

```
if ( rnumnonpx.test( ret ) && rmargin.test( name ) ) {
            width = style.width;
            minWidth = style.minWidth;
            maxWidth = style.maxWidth;

            style.minWidth = style.maxWidth = style.width = ret;
            ret = computed.width;

            style.width = width;
            style.minWidth = minWidth;
            style.maxWidth = maxWidth;
        }
```

How to recover this ? Please help.

Comment: Do you really mean [Mozilla](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/products/mozilla1.x/) or are you talking about Firefox?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox @Quentin

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle of demo. which is easy for users to solve your issue. ☺